# Can I get DataMember names in the code?

Tags: c#, xml, datamember

in one project, I use datamember to serialize a class to an xml file, like,

```
[DataMember]
public string Member1;
```

later I query the xml to get one value out, like:

```
XmlNode1.SelectSingleNode("Member1");
```

Is it possible that make the `Member1` above to a variable so when I change the `DataMember` name to be `Member2` the `Member1` in the query can be changed to `Member2` automatically ,rather than I manually change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure I understand what you hope to achieve, but I am thinking if you want to be able to centrally control the output from the serialization, you could define the tag in say a public static class.

```
static class SerializationConstants
{
  public static string MemberTag = "Member1"; //or "Member2"
}
```

Then in your datamember you can use the property with the Name attribute.

```
[DataMember(Name=SerializationConstants.MemberTag)
public string Member1;
```

That would control serialization such that in your code for querying the xml, you can do something like:

```
XmlNode1.SelectSingleNode(SerializationConstants.MemberTag)
```

It would be a hack but I guess it should do if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: it looks this can work when I make the MemberTag const. I ll take this as the answer if there s no other easy ways...

Answer (score 0):

You should deserialize the XML file when working with it, then you can use field names to access properties and they would change if you would do refactoring.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Deserialization can do it, just in my situation, I only need one value, but desrializtion will deserialize the whole class. Is that too much to get the small value?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a great idea.

If you are concerned about property names changing in your class with the DataMember attribute, you are probably going to want a layer of abstraction in the form of a DTO between that class and your XML querying. That way your XML querying class doesn't care if that member name changes or not because your DTO will never change. Just the mapping from the DTO to the volitle class.

Comment: DTO is Data Transfer Object? I read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978717.aspx ... seems quite complicated to relate with my problem...

Comment: It allows you to maintain a class that never changes. If your class with the datamember attribute changes alot, all you would have to change is the mapping from the class whose data you want and the DTO object that always will have the data you need. That way, no code changes need to be made outside of the mapping.